# Angular JS find minimum value in a row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which fetches amounts in row. Need to find minimum amount on that row
I am trying this code but I am getting vm.MinimumAmount as nan

```
  <td ng-repeat="total in vm.Totals" ng-init="vm.minAmount(vm.Totals)" >{{total.Total | currency}} </td>

function minAmount(totalarray) {
        vm.MinimumAmount = Math.min(totalarray) 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.min takes in a vararg of arguments, not an array, so you can do this instead:

```
vm.MinimumAmount = Math.min.apply(Math, totalarray);
```

Comment: for some reason totalarray is undefined though when I do a console.log(totalarray) I see values but when I put this in Math.min it gives me infinity

Comment: I also tried this  $scope.$watch('vm.Totals', function (newVal, oldVal) {
console.log('totalnew',newVal);           
                var newArray = Enumerable.From(newVal).ToArray();
                vm.MinimumAmount = Enumerable.From(newArray).OrderByDescending($.Total);
               // vm.MinimumAmount = Math.min.apply(Math, newArray);
                console.log('minimum', vm.MinimumAmount); });
html: <td ng-repeat="total in vm.Totals" ng-model="vm.Totals" >{{total.Total | currency}} </td> again i can see values in newval but i get error parent undefined